# Accessing DataContractJsonSerializer<T> properties via re-factored foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datacontractjsonserializer

I have the code below.

The line `string content = twitterMsg.text;` is creating the error 'Use of unassigned local variable' for twitterMsg. I don't seem able to access my `TwitterSearchResponse.results.text` fields in my `DataContractJsonSerializer<TwitterMain>` collection.

`TwitterSearchResponse.results` is an array (set of object properties) with several string fields attached with names like `text` and `user_info`.

Can anyone help with this??

**Updated** code below. I am still highly confused about why I am not able to iterate over my `TwitterSearchResponse.results` properly and assign `content = twitterMsg.text`

For what it's worth, here is my DataContractJsonSerializer method:

```
String url = String.Format("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q={0}&rpp=20", Server.UrlEncode(txtSearchFor.Text));


// parse the JSON data
using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(wc.DownloadData(url)))
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer =
        new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TwitterMain));
    TwitterSearchResponse = jsonSerializer.ReadObject(ms) as TwitterMain;  // read as JSON and map as TwitterOut
}
```

And here is the original posted code where the issue lies.

```
    public List<MatchCollection> returnMatches(DataContractJsonSerializer<TwitterMain> TwitterSearchResponse)
{
        List<MatchCollection> messageLinks = new List<MatchCollection>();

        foreach (TwitterResult twitterMsg in TwitterSearchResponse.results)
        {
            string content = twitterMsg.text;

            // capture internet protocol pre-fixed words from message
            string pattern = @"...";
            messageLinks.Add(Regex.Matches(content, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

            // capture @username twitter users from message
            string atUsernamePattern = @"@([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)";
            MatchCollection PeopleMatches = Regex.Matches(content, atUsernamePattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        }

        return messageLinks;
}
```

Comment: I have removed my RegEx `pattern` as it was making SO behave strangely (wouldn't let me post!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect it's *actually* reporting the use of the unassigned local variable `MessageLinks`. Your use of `twitterMsg` looks fine.

So, the big question is: what do you want to return if there *aren't* any results? If you're happy returning null, just assign the value when you declare `MessageLinks`.

Next question: do you really only want to return the last `MatchCollection` you find? That's what the current behaviour is: you're looping over all the variables, setting the same local variable each time (i.e. replacing the previous value) and then returning that last value.

Final question: any reason why you've got a camel-cased method name (`returnMatches`), a Pascal-cased local variable (`MessageLinks`), a Pascal-cased parameter name (`TwitterSearchResponse`) and a camel-cased property (`text`)? I would assume that `text` is due to it coming from JSON that way - but it's a good idea to follow normal .NET naming conventions otherwise.

Comment: I seem to have my own notation that is almost certainly not so useful. Thanks, I understand the issue now and will make sure I keep good formatting from now on!

Comment: @ Jon Skeet - actually I have used `public List<MatchCollection> returnMatches(DataContractJsonSerializer<TwitterMain> TwitterSearchResponse)` to get all MatchCollections, but twitterMsg is still not getting access to it's data.

Comment: @AlexW: Please post the *actual code* - omitting the pattern if necessary, of course. Your currently posted code would *not* lead to the error message you posted.

Comment: Ok it's fine now, I ran the debugger and it cleared itself up somehow.